# System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families includes a font family with empty name on Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows, fonts

On .NET on Windows, using System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families returns empty name as the following Quick Watch shown.

The font seems to be still usable, but it is not to list up empty name as a font choice.  So, I'm wondering if I should opt out this one, or if there's any way to obtain actual name of this font family.

This happens with multiple machines with Windows 10.  This was not happening before and it does not happen on Windows 7 machine, so I believe it is due to recent Windows 10's update

Here's the code

```
System.Drawing.FontFamily[] Families = System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families;
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image: Quick Watch shows Name is actually empty]

Comment: Can confirm this happens on Win 10. This is really weird, because `FontFamily` constructor throws an `ArgumentException` if given an empty name.

Comment: Hi Asti, thank you very much for your reply.  Yes, the issue IS happening on Windows 10 with multiple machines.